# supervisord environment variable it is not pass to test_app.sh

Tags: bash, environment-variables, supervisord

supervisord 3.1.1

I am trying to pass variable from supervisord config to the test_app.sh

```
[program:test_app]
command   = /home/korek/webapps/test_app.sh
user = korek
environment=DBPASSWD="dbpasswd", DBLOGIN="dblogin", EPASSWD="epasswd", ELOGIN="elogin"
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile = /home/korek/webapps/logs/gunicorn-supervisor.log
```

But the test_app.sh environment is not set.

```
#!/bin/bash
env
set
echo "DBPASSWD: ${DBPASSWD}"
```

Returns standard environment without DBPASS, DBLOGIN, EPASS, ELOGIN.

**Update:**

supervisorctl

```
test_app                     RUNNING   pid 3994, uptime 0:10:05
```

Log from /tmp/supervisor.log

```
2015-10-12 15:16:20,130 INFO spawned: 'test_app' with pid 3994
2015-10-12 15:16:21,376 INFO success: test_app entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Log from /home/korek/webapps/logs/gunicorn-supervisor.log

```
DBPASSWD: 
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [3994] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  proxy_protocol: False
  worker_connections: 1000
  statsd_host: None
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x1632500>
  pythonpath: None
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  worker_class: sync
  ssl_version: 3
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  syslog: False
  syslog_facility: user
  when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x1632230>
  pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x1632398>
  cert_reqs: 0
  preload_app: False
  keepalive: 2
  accesslog: None
  group: 999
  graceful_timeout: 30
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  spew: False
  workers: 3
  proc_name: test_app
  sendfile: True
  pidfile: None
  umask: 7
  on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x16320c8>
  pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x1632aa0>
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x1632668>
  limit_request_fields: 100
  on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x16361b8>
  config: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x1632c08>
  post_request: <function post_request at 0x1632cf8>
  user: 7947
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x16327d0>
  threads: 1
  max_requests: 0
  limit_request_line: 4094
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  certfile: None
  worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x1632e60>
  chdir: /home/korek/webapps/
  paste: None
  default_proc_name: deployment.wsgi:application
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  logconfig: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog_prefix: None
  daemon: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x162fed8>
  worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x1632938>
  bind: ['unix:/home/korek/webapps/run/gunicorn.sock']
  raw_env: []
  reload: False
  check_config: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x1636050>
  timeout: 30
  ca_certs: None
  django_settings: None
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  keyfile: None
  backlog: 2048
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  statsd_prefix: 
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [3994] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [3994] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [3994] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/korek/webapps/run/gunicorn.sock (3994)
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [3994] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [4010] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4010
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [4011] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4011
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [4012] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4012
[2015-10-12 15:16:20 +0000] [3994] [DEBUG] 3 workers
[2015-10-12 15:16:21 +0000] [3994] [DEBUG] 3 workers
```

test_app is working because i did not yet changed passwords to environment passwords.

Comment: What returns? `supervisorctl` and what shows log file?

Comment: Did you reload the supervisord process? If not, then you can do it using `supervisorctl` and then `reload`

Comment: yes that was it, just figured it out, thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that i did stop and start just `test_app` and i should restart whole supervisord `/etc/rc.d/rc.supervisord restart` or just reaload `test_app` as grimsock advised.

It's working now.